# Set delete rules Magical Record

Tags: objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

hope you're well on that Friday evening.

It's been an hour now that I am looking for an answer on the Internet.

I encounter some issues deleting entities using Magical Record. I have a table view where are displayed some attributes of my entities. When I press a cell, an other view with some details about the concerned entity is revealed. Then the entity can be deleted by pressing a button.

The problem : the entity is only deleted for a short time, then it appears again in the table view.

I read that post : [Deleting entity in MagicalRecord is not persisting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14992129/deleting-entity-in-magicalrecord-is-not-persisting)

But I can't find how to set these "delete rules".

Thanks in advance.

Edit : here is the deletion code :

```
    Flag *flag = self.flag;
    NSNumber *flagIdNum = flag.id;
    NSDate *flagTime = flag.time;

    [flag MR_deleteEntity];
    Flag *upgradedFlag = [Flag MR_createEntity];
    upgradedFlag.message = self.flagTextField.text;
    upgradedFlag.id = flagIdNum;
    upgradedFlag.time = flagTime;
    upgradedFlag.place = self.place;
    [LocalDB saveWithCompletion:^{}];
```

And here is the saveWithCompletion method :

```
+ (void)saveWithCompletion:(void (^)(void))callbackBlock
 {

   [[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext] MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];

   [[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext] MR_saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
       if (success) {
           NSLog(@"You successfully saved your context.");
       } else if (error) {
           NSLog(@"Error saving context: %@", error.description);
       }
       callbackBlock();
   }];

}
```

Actually, what I am trying to do is updating the entity "flag" to give it an other "place" attribute. I didn't find how to change an entity attribute so I try to delete the entity and then replace it.
Even if it is possible to change an entity attribute, I would like to know how to delete an entity.

It is good pointing out that the attribute "place" is a relationship with an other entity.

Thanks again !

Comment: Can you show your deletion code. Also, are you saving after the delete?

Comment: You could try asking @EdwardChin who posted the answer you linked.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I just added the deletion code. Actually, the entity reappears after a short time, even if I don't close the app.